# Java Desktop Application and Paypal Integration

Tags: java, paypal

I have a freeware desktop Java(Fx) application, and I currently have a donate button in the app, that simply opens up a web browser and points to the standard donate url (created with the Paypal Donate Buttons tool).

Now, I'd like to add some premade amounts in the app (and a custom one), e.g. "Donate $5", "Donate $10", "Donate Custom Amount".

I've peeked at this webpage, https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/, but I am a bit overwhelmed / unsure how to proceed... I'd really like to keep this as simple as possible.

Could someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Go for Paypal Payments Pro. You will get Hosted check out page solution. I think it is the simplest solution. Because you don't need to design any pages for the payment. As soon as the user clicks on the 'Donate' button, you can make the user to redirect to the Paypal Hosted Check out page. And then on all the payment will be taken care by the paypal. And finally the user will be redirected to your application.

You can customise how the Hosted check out page should look like by logging into manager paypal account.

Most importantly you can configure things like SuccessUrl, FailureUrl and CancelUrl. And by thus after the payment the paypal redirects the user to your application easily.

I think this is one of the easiest solution out there.